# Same NSDate code yields different results on iOS7 and iOS6

Tags: ios, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

In this code, I have an NSString *s with a fixed-format date such as: @"2013-12-06T16:30:00-06:00".

After the code is run, self.date is nil on iOS6 and correctly interpreted as an NSDate object on iOS7. Any ideas?

```
NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ"];
self.date = [f dateFromString:s];
```

Comment: For that timezone format you should be using `ZZZZZ`, not `ZZ`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time zone formatting `ZZ` doesn't accept `-06:00`.

The difference between iOS 6 and iOS 7 date parsing is that iOS 6 is more unforgiving.

For more info about the correct date formatting patterns, go to http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: Thank you for your input. I changed my ZZ to ZZZZZ and it worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @user2917941 Note you can use `-[NSDateFormatter getObjectValue:forString:range:error:]` to get the error message when `dateFromString` returns `nil`.

Comment: @user2917941 Why did you accept this answer? It doesn't tell you how to fix the problem.